# What is the difference in using an iOS dependency as pod and using it from node modules?

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, node-modules

I have to add a dependency

```
@react-native-community/netinfo
```

to my iOS project, here I can add it directly to the podfile as

```
pod 'react-native-netinfo', :git => 'https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-netinfo.git', :tag => 'v9.3.6'
```

or I can add it to my package.json as

```
"@react-native-community/netinfo": "9.3.6"
```

and use it in the podfile as

```
pod 'react-native-netinfo', :path => 'nodemodules/react-native-info'
```

Which of the 2 approaches is better and why?
Are there any particular scenarios when I should use one over the other?
Relatively new to React native. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Approach 1: This is more useful if you directly want to hit a specific git repo. The example you provided will have the same behavior in both the cases but targeting a git repo can be immensely useful in case of customization or forked repos

Approach 2: this essentially automates the process of code lookup and offloads the responsibility to the npm packages which is safe and will probably prevent unexpected bugs in the long run.

You mentioned being new to RN. Stick to 2 for now for normal purposes.

Comment: Thanks!
How does approach 2 make it safer and prevent unexpected bugs when both use the same version?

Comment: As soon you update your corresponding npm package version in package.json ( something that will happen frequently) approach one will immediately break while 2 will keep working nicely